# Фильтрация данных в GetFiles по нескольким расширениям

Tags: c++, файловая-система, фильтрация

Пишу код (С++ Builder) получения списка файлов с маской по нескольким расширениям файлов. Как работать с 1 расширением разобрался, но как передать массив расширений не понимаю. Так ищу для какого то одного расширения:

```
TStringDynArray listFile;
listFile = TDirectory::GetFiles(/целевой каталог/,/расширение файла *.х/); 
for (int n = 0; n < listFile.Length; n++)
  {
   // обработка данных
  }
```

В справке есть данные по GetFiles:

`GetFiles(const System::UnicodeString Path, const _di_TFilterPredicate Predicate)`

где `_di_TFilterPredicate Predicate` - представляет тип метода, используемый при фильтрации результатов поиска файлов. Но как его использовать так и не догнал.
На [англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726756/how-to-pass-multiple-file-extensions-to-tdirectory-getfiles) сайта есть интересующая меня тема, но там рассматривается код на delphi.

Подскажите пожалуйста физический смысл `_di_TFilterPredicate` чтоб разобраться с фильтрацией.